# Django pass value to subquery inside annotate in a query set with mptt

Tags: django, django-queryset

i have a class based on ListCreateAPIView where i'm modifing get_queryset method..
i need pass inside a subquery for an annotate a paramether but seem OutherRef dosen't work

i'm using Mptt library ....
subqueryItem works fine,
subqueryNested instead says "This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery."

```
  def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super().get_queryset()


        subqueryItem = Subquery(Item.objects.filter(category=OuterRef('id')).order_by()
                        .values('category').annotate(count=Count('pk'))
                        .values('count'), output_field=IntegerField())

        subqueryNested = Subquery(Item.objects.filter(category__in=ItemCategory.objects.get(pk=OuterRef('id')).get_descendants(include_self=True)).order_by()
                        .values('category').annotate(count=Count('pk'))
                        .values('count'), output_field=IntegerField())


        queryset = queryset.annotate(
            collcount        = Coalesce(subqueryItem, 0),
            collcountdeep    = Coalesce(subqueryNested, 0),
        )
```

Comment: I think you are giving brackets in a wrong way.

Comment: can you explain a bit more?